# Why aren't my text labels appearing?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to figure out why my text labels aren't showing up. I don't see any sort of error in the console, just ... no labels.

```
  svg.selectAll("text")
           .data(data)
           .enter().append("text")
           .text(function(d) {
             return (d.money);
             })
           .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
           .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.year); })
           .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.money); })
           .attr("class", "axis");
```

The full example is at https://jsfiddle.net/s3jo8gkL/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, you are selecting all the `text` elements, and you already have texts in your SVG. Just change your first line, selecting any given class (or any given ID, any fake element or even any SVG element that doesn't exist at that point):

```
svg.selectAll(".thistext")
       .data(data)
       .enter().append("text")
       .text(function(d) {
         return (d.money);
         })
       .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
       .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.year); })
       .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.money); })
       .attr("class", "axis");
```

Comment: The text elements already have a class of "axis," so you should use that in the selection rather than "thistext"

Comment: That was just an example. Actually, you can use anything, like `selectAll("xkcd")`.